# Making common function in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.4

I am new in cakephp, i want to know  how to create a common function.

That means i have some code which will be repeated in multiple controllers at multiple time.
So i want to make this codes into a function and us in different controllers.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Put the function in AppController.php because every controller extends this class. So you can access that function using `$this->yourFunction();`